# Can grid-based clustering method be use for customer segmentation?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering

I am trying some clustering methods for customer segmentation and I stumbled upon grid based methods like: STING, MAFIA, WAVE CLUSTER, and CLIQUE. However, from what i've read, most of them are for image segmentation.

So before I invest my time in implementing these algorithms, I would like to know if anyone has tried using grid based clustering for clustering customer data before or on something that is not image based?

Comment: I don't understand why you got the downvotes. It's really annoying when someone downvotes without bothering to explain, especially to someone new to the site.

Comment: yeah i mean i dont mind downvote if they give me an explanation whats wrong with my question tough. Probably they think im trolling from my username

Comment: Welcome to this forum. I didn't downvote this question, but let me explain why people will downvote you. You did not provide enough information, for example what kind of data or features do you have for you customer segmentation task, how many dimensions, how mange segments you want, etc. Without this information, any answer would only be based on subjective opinions instead of fact, valid argument or convincing references, and not very likely to be helpful for others.

Comment: ah i see my bad ill provide more detail next time , thx @user12075

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Depends on what your customer data is, but here's an idea:

You can look for a way to map your customer data on a 2D plot. Then you could save these plots as rasters (images in a lossless format, ML libraries commonly use .tiff). Make sure to strip decorations, scales, labels and anything that is not pure data representation, so that now every pixel in the raster represents what has now become a datapoint for you.

If you achieve this, you would be able to apply the desired algorithms on the newly created images.

The advantage of such an approach is that you add (or rather underline preexising) topological properties to your data, such as the proximity of what now become your pixels. It should go without saying that such properties should be utilised only if they contextually make sense for your data. And due to the existence of a continuous distance metric on numerical dimensions, the proximity example is better applicable to such numerical dimensions.

Comment: okay didnt think that through. Thanks for the answer

Comment: That has to be the most convoluted way to cluster data

Comment: "Convoluted" is definitely the right word. Don't see how it leads to a downvote though. This is simply data preprocessing by exploring a 2-dimensional relationship.

Comment: I think it is misleading to call it an image, since it does not represent any objects/visuals - I would rather call it a discretization, which is, as I would assume, exactly what grid-based methods do by nature.

Comment: Would "save these plots as discretisations in a .tiff format" sound better? Maybe if I use "rasterisation" would be best? I'm sorry, but I'm missing the point of the criticism. Please, explain.

Comment: Having seen that the approach is underappreciated by quite a few, I expanded my answer to explain the rationale behind raster mapping and preprocessing that allows for spacial modelling of data.